# Working with data from Numato ADC in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a Python script that reads ADC data from a Numato board, slices the recieved bytes to retrieve the data, which will be an integer between 0 and 1023, and alters that value to give a value of electrical current. This value is inserted into a Numpy array, along with the time at which the reading was taken.

This code is throwing the error 'TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not tuple'.

The snippet of the script involved in retrieving the data is as follows:

```
def readdata(a, serPort):
global elapsed
serPort.write(str.encode("adc read 0 " +v "\r"))
response = serPort.read(25)
current = response[8,-8]*0.0322265625
b = numpy.array([elapsed, current])
```

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you.

UPDATE: The typo at response[8,-8] has been amended to now read:

```
response[8,:-8]
```

A different error is now being thrown, as:

```
TypeError: can't concat into bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `response[8,-8]`. You have used the tuple (8,-8) as the index, this cannot work for a byte array. (Numpy objects do support this and other kinds of complex indices. Byte arrays on the other hand accept only an integer or a slice as an index).

To get a part of the data that you received from your device, use a slice, e.g.:

```
response[4:8] # get 4 bytes at offsets 4,5,6,7
```

Note a slice of type `bytes` is also `bytes`, you will not be able to use it in arithmetic operations, such as multiplying it by a floating-point number. You will have to convert the bytes to a Python integer value first. Use the `struct` module to do this. [7.1. struct — Interpret bytes as packed binary data](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/struct.html). Here's how you can get a 4-byte big-endian integer (from offset 4, just as an example):

```
value = struct.unpack(">I", response[4:8])
```

Comment: Ah, that was a typo in the code; I'll fix in in the OP. Thank you very much.

Now I'm recieving a different error:

TypeError: can't concat int to bytes

Comment: After implementing the struct.unpack, I'm now getting error:

struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

Comment: If you used response[8:-8], you would get a slice that's 9 bytes long (you read 25 bytes, therefore response[8:-8] is the same as response[8:25-8] == response[8:17]. I don't know the structure of data returned by your device, you will need to read its manual to find out which part of those 25 bytes is the value that you want and whether it is big-endian or little-endian, signed or unsigned, etc (and whether it is 4 bytes or longer, could be 8). Then, you should pick the correct format string to give to struct.unpack().